# Traffic lights onload function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on this in notepad but errors keep occurring. What's wrong with my code? i am trying to make an onload traffic light with an object array. It is an obligation to do it through an array.

```
<html>

<body onload="loop()">
<div style="background:black;width:75px;height:140px;margin:auto;"> 
<div id ="red" style="background:red;width:40px;height:40px;border-radius:40px;margin:auto;"></div>
        <div id = "yellow" style="background:#3F4A00;width:40px;height:40px;border-radius:40px;margin:auto"></div>
        <div id = "green" style="background:#044A00;width:40px;height:40px;border-radius:40px;margin:auto"></div>
    <!--The style refers to css, the background  -->
    </div>
    <script>
    var redlight = document.getElementById('redlight');
    var yellowlight = document.getElementById('yellowlight');
    var greenlight = document.getElementById('greenlight');
    var colors = ["rgb(255, 0, 0)",'rgb(82, 2, 2)','rgb(255, 255, 0)','rgb(63, 74, 0)','rgb(0, 128, 0)','rgb(4, 74, 0)'];
function loop() {

    if  (redlight.style.backgroundColor == colors[0]){
        redlight.style.backgroundColor = colors[1]; //switch off red
        yellowlight.style.backgroundColor = colors[2]; //switch on yellow
    }
    else if (yellowlight.style.backgroundColor == colors[2]) {
        yellowlight.style.backgroundColor = colors[3]; //switch off yellow
        greenlight.style.backgroundColor = colors[4]; //switch on green
    }
    else if (greenlight.style.backgroundColor == colors[4]) {
        greenlight.style.backgroundColor = colors[5]; //switch off green
        redlight.style.backgroundColor = colors[0]; //switch on red
    }
            setInterval(function() {
},3000); //this sets the intervals for each traffic light to change colors
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're doing getElementById like

```
var redlight = document.getElementById('redlight');
var yellowlight = document.getElementById('yellowlight');
var greenlight = document.getElementById('greenlight');
```

And your divs have ids of: red, yellow, and green

```
<div id ="red" style="background:red;width:40px;height:40px;border-radius:40px;margin:auto;"></div>
<div id = "yellow" style="background:#3F4A00;width:40px;height:40px;border-radius:40px;margin:auto"></div>
<div id = "green" style="background:#044A00;width:40px;height:40px;border-radius:40px;margin:auto"></div>
```

Change the div ids to redlight, yellowlight, and greenlight.

```
<div id ="redlight" style="background:red;width:40px;height:40px;border-radius:40px;margin:auto;"></div>
<div id = "yellowlight" style="background:#3F4A00;width:40px;height:40px;border-radius:40px;margin:auto"></div>
<div id = "greenlight" style="background:#044A00;width:40px;height:40px;border-radius:40px;margin:auto"></div>
```

Also

1. change the background color on the redlight to: #ff0000
2. move the setInterval outside of the loop function.
3. change the setInterval to setInterval(loop,3000);

Here is a working js fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/n1b1htaz/1/